# Dynamical number of columns in SQL query in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to create a PL/SQL function which will return formatted HTML table content from given SQL query. SQL input query could have different number of columns. So if I send the query like `SELECT x,y,z FROM mytable` my function should return a table with three columns (and many rows).

In order to build formatted table I have to loop through different number of columns and fill HTML rows (TR) with cells (TD). How to find the dynamical number of columns in given SQL query!?

Comment: Why do you need the oracle to do that? If you are serving HTML as final output, let your application layer handles this. Any database driver once resultset is returned can give you the amount of fetched columns easily.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos, I know that and in normal circumstances that would do my application layer, but here I need to create batch job which will send (using UTIL_MAIL) an e-mail with results and I want this content to be formatted as HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLSQL method. With dbms_xmlgen and xlt transform.

```
 DECLARE  
    v_ctx  dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
    v_query  varchar2(2000) := 'SELECT * FROM user_objects WHERE rownum  < 10';        -- your query here
    v_xsl_transform  xmltype := xmltype('<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="html"/>
     <xsl:template match="/ROWSET">
     <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="ROW[1]/*">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ROW">
     <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ROW/*">
     <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>'); 


     v_html  clob; 
   BEGIN 
     v_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newContext(v_query);
     dbms_xmlgen.setNullHandling(v_ctx, dbms_xmlgen.EMPTY_TAG);
     dbms_xmlgen.setXSLT(v_ctx, v_xsl_transform);        
     select xmlserialize(document dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType(v_ctx) as clob indent size =4) into v_html from dual;
     dbms_xmlgen.closeContext(v_ctx); 
     dbms_output.put_line(v_html); 
   END;
   /
```

Comment: Thanks @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz, I just edited smaller error `<xsl:apply-templates/>` goes after `</tr>` in your XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL*Plus you use:

```
set markup HTML ON entmap off
```

I believe there is HTML formatting provided by a standard Oracle PL/SQL package